# Local Vis Aura maximum dropped?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-thaumcraft

I managed to find a Silverwood Sapling the other day and planted it on top of my house (which is pretty much just a hole in the ground). After several days, it finally grew into a tree and I noticed something odd. Originally, my local Aura was 468/468. However, when my tree grew, it dropped to 95/95. While the Flux dropped from High to None (and is now stabilized at Minimal), I find it odd that the maximum Aura dropped when a Silverwood Tree is supposed to spawn an Aura Node.

Is this a bug or is there some other explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Goggles of Revealing show you the values of the nearest aura node. Since that silverwood tree created a *new* aura node closer to your base, that's what your local aura is now.

The pure silverwood aura nodes are usually this small. It doesn't really matter though, since it will still be recharged by other nearby nodes (including the original 468 one). Plus, since it's pure, it will deal with all the crap you'll be dumping into the aura.

Comment: I went down to mine for the first time since I planted my tree and I noticed that the aura levels returned to their original values after descending several minecraft-distance-units.

Answer (score 0):

The Silverwood aura is 93. If you know where your other aura node is it will still be 468. If you plant Silverwood trees near the other Silverwood node you can make the node bigger. I did that, and I have a pure node of over 1000 now.